# How can i read string and integer, on same line from a text file?

Tags: c++

I have this example,

On my .txt file i have “Jorge Saraiva 1321312”

my .cpp

```
string line, nome;
int number;

ifstream ifi("nameOfFile.txt");

 if(!ifi.is_open()){
   cout << "Error opening file" << ends;
 }
 {
  else{
    while( getline(ifi,line) ){
      istringstream is(line);

       is >> nome; 
       is >> number; 
    }
    ifi.close();
  }
 cout << nome  << endl << number << ends;
```

With this i only got first name ("Jorge"), I'm not sure how can i tell compiler when the name/string ends.

Comment: How would you tell a human in plain English when the name ends?

Comment: Why don't you read the name into two strings for first and last name?

Comment: @EliSadoff Good idea, but if i wanted to have full name "Jorge Silva Pereira", i mean, imagine i have many names, and that names some are 3 words, others 4, others 5, how can i know when string ends ?

Comment: That's exactly what @ChristianHackl said: you have to know what the input "looks like" before you can write code to decipher it. So for "Jorge Silva Pereira 1321312" and for "Jorge Pereira 1321312", what's the rule?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/99243/). This provides some help as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you familiar with stringstream?

Comment: Your sample program already shows that you know everything that needs to be known to do this. You know how to parse a string into whitespace-delimited words using `operator>>`. Use this to pull apart each line, and place each word into a vector of strings. After you're done, the last word is going to be your number, so remove it from the vector, convert it to the integer, then reassemble the remaining words in the vector in a single string, with whitespace-delimited words. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put string (2nd one) into a number, that is the cause of unexpected output. [Directing it to a string](http://ideone.com/1PGoxN) should fix that. You can discard the string, doesn't matter.

```
string line, name, dummy;
int number;
while(getline(ifi, line)){  
    istringstream iss1(line);
    iss1 >> name; 
    iss1 >> dummy;
    iss1 >> number; 
}
```

Comment: you can choose to do in one line iss1 >> name >> dummy >> number...makes your code more terse..:)

Answer (score 1):

There's one solution I can see for your problem. If you want to have multiple names (no matter the size) and then a number on front you can take advantage form the isdigit function.

In your while cycle when reading from the file you can add something like:

```
String temp;
is >> name; 

    while (is){
    is >> temp; 

    if(isdigit(temp[0])){
            int number = atoi(temp.c_str()); } 
    else {
          name += " " + temp;
       }
    }
```

That way you can have multiple sized names.

I'm writing on a phone so it's harder but you can get an idea of what I'm talking about. Yet don't forget to include the  library.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, when dealing with csv files, your data is delimited with semicolon or some other character. In you case you dont have it, so you must do more advanced parsing. You may use regexps for that:

```
#include <regex>

// ...

// Pattern
std::regex pattern("([^\\d]+)\\s*([\\d ]+)" );

// ...

// And instead of istringstream
std::smatch sm;
if (std::regex_match(line, sm, pattern)) {
  nome = sm[1];
  number = std::stoi(sm[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to keep extracting as an integer, unless successful

```
int number;
string name;

istringstream record(line);

// keep trying till a number is found.
record >> number;
while (record.fail() && !record.eof()) {
    record.clear();

    string temp;
    record >> temp;
    name.append(temp);

    record >> number;
}

cout << "Name: "   << name   << endl;
cout << "Number: " << number << endl;
```

Complete Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        int number;
        string name;

        istringstream record(line);

        // keep trying till a number is found.
        record >> number;
        while (record.fail() && !record.eof()) {
            record.clear();
            string temp;
            record >> temp;
            name.append(temp);
            record >> number;
        }

        cout << "Name: "   << name   << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << number << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
string line, firstname,lastname;
int number;

ifstream ifi("nameOfFile.txt");

if (!ifi.is_open()) 
{
cout << "Error opening file" << ends;
}
else
{
while (ifi>>firstname>>lastname>>number) {}
ifi.close();
}
cout << firstname <<endl<<lastname <<endl << number << ends;
```

Comment: If there are multiple lines in file then you save it in array and this process will done in while loop.