# Parsing a string form a text file and dividing it into two variables in c++

Tags: c++, parsing

I basically need to read a text file with names of students and their ID's line by line. Each student will be a node. I need to divide the name and ID into two separate variables namely value(name) and key(ID). The problem is that the name can consist of a first name and last name or can consist of a first, last, and middle name while some names might only consist of a first name. No matter how many parts the name has, it needs to be in one variable. The delimiter is "~" between the complete name and ID.The problem I'm having is that when I print my key alone the ID's are printed of all the students, but when i also print my value(name) the ID's and names start printing from the 29th student (total of about 200 students). Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

```
example of a few lines from the text where a,b,c are names:
a b c 12345678
a c 79399217




#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct TreeNode
{
    std::string value;
    T key;
    TreeNode<T>* right;
    TreeNode<T>* left;
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream file_("names.txt");
    std::string line_;
    while(std::getline(file_, line_)){
        TreeNode<int>* n = new TreeNode<int>;
        std::string delimiter = "~";
        std::string node_value = line_.substr(0,line_.find(delimiter));
        n->value=node_value;
        std::stringstream linestream(line_);
        int node_key;
        std::getline(linestream, node_value, '\~');
        linestream>>node_key;
        n->key=node_key;
        std::cout<<n->key<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<n->value<<std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the issue is how to take a string and divide it into several pieces, write a simple program that takes a string and attempts to do that.  Introducing Treenodes and other irrelevant items just clutters things up.  Once you get that simple program to work, *then* you introduce that into your larger program.

Comment: Is this the same homework assignment as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439057/how-can-i-read-string-and-integer-on-same-line-from-a-text-file? I don't know whether to laugh, or cry.

Comment: I need to use the nodes later on. So each loop of my while loop should create a new node with a new student information.

Comment: @CS.R -- Programs are developed a piece at a time.  It doesn't matter what you want to do later with those strings.  If the issue is that you cannot simply divide a string into the relevant parts, then work solely on that.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @CS.R - Create a function, called `void split_string(const std::string& src, std::string& s1, std::string& s2);`  where src is the original string, and s1 and s2 on return will return the splitted string.  Work on the body of this function to do what you're asking.  Call this function in a test `main` function with different data to see if it works, Once you get it working, you've now got code that you can add to your larger program.  No need for TreeNodes, or any other irrelevant things to get started with this.

Comment: you mention `~` as delimiter, but in you example `a b c` there are none

Comment: @CS.R:  I second the "just split a string first" approach.  See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/} by Eric Lippert.

Comment: You should not escape the tilde `'\~'` just use `'~'`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @tobi303 sorry that was a typo. Should be like a b c~ 123456789

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your advice. I did what you said and made a  split string function first and then worked on the nodes. It worked!